# Confusion regarding selectors in carousel/slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I'm pretty new to javascript/jquery. Recently i've made a website, that changes the color of the frame depending on what you select from a carousel/slider.

Everything is operational, only issue is, I just can't quite wrap my head around how to properly apply selector to elements of my carousel.

Basically my carousel looks something like this

[image: carousel]

What I want to do, is, I've set the third border/frame to be hidden. 
Now, whenever you **click the left arrow** the element closest to the left will switch to hidden, while, the image to the right of it will take it's position and the previously hidden image will appear.

The opposite goes to right, I've made it like this:

[image: carousel working]

So everything is working as expected, only issue is, this will only work once (mainly because I don't know which selector to use).

To put things into context, my HTML (specifically for the carousel) looks like this

```
    <div id="selector">
    <img id="goleft" src="images/left.png" />
    <div>
        <img id="blue" src="images/shot-blue.png" />
        <img id="yellow" src="images/shot-yellow.png" />
        <img id="red" src="images/shot-red.png" />
    </div>
    <img id="goright" src="images/right.png" />
</div>
```

Nothing too difficult

My jQuery is very basic as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //Set the last (red) image to be hidden
      $("#selector div img:last").hide();
      // If we click left, hide the first one and show the last one
      $("#goleft").click(function(){
        $("#selector div img:first").hide('slow')
        $("#selector div img:last").show('slow')
      });
      // Similar for right
      $("#goright").click(function(){
        $("#selector div img:last").hide('slow')
        $("#selector div img:first").show('slow')
      });
    });
</script>
```

Only issue is, the `:first` and `:last` selector literally select the first and last image instead of the first visible and last hidden element

So basically my carousel stops working after first rotation (on both sides)

Any idea how to properly apply the selector so the rotation is endless?

Answer (score 0):

> the :first and :last selector literally select the first and last
>   image instead of the first visible and last hidden element

You can use hidden and visible selector and use the last and first methods of jquery:

```
$("#selector div img:hidden").first().show();    
$("#selector div img:visible").last().hide();
```

Update: note that you can not immediately run these statements one after another otherwise you will have jquery execute statements on something that is not yet hidden. What you can do to prevent this is to use the callback function on show and hide like this:

```
$("#selector div img:visible").last().hide('slow', function()
    {
      $("#selector div img:hidden").first().show('slow');
    }
);
```

Here is also a jsfiddle with the full implementation:

https://jsfiddle.net/4sh7cnub/

I used span with some css instead of images so you need to change span to img for your own case.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with the implementation? I've tried using these, but unfortunately they do not seem to do anything. Unless I've missunderstood how they are supposed to be applied.